# Como fazer uma UITableViewCell funcionar como ao Facebook Messenger para iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewcell

Como criar uma `UITableView`, onde as células mantenham o texto em negrito, até que sejam tocadas, e salvar essa alteração?

Por exemplo, quando recebemos uma mensagem no Facebook o texto na `UITableViewCell` fica em negrito, após tocar na célula e ver e voltar à `UITableView`, o texto da célula não fica mais em negrito.

Exemplo, Imagem Abaixo:

Abaixo o código que tentei, mas não funcionou:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
.
.
.
//Implementation
.
.
.
// Atualiza o estado de NÃO LIDO para LIDO no banco de dados

 [[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"lido"];

    NSError*error;

    // Escreve no banco a alteração
    [context save:&error];

    for (int index = 0; index<[fetchedObjects count]; index++) {

        NSLog(@"%@",[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"lido"]);

.
.
.
// Implementation

}




-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
.
.
.

//Implmentation

.
.
.

 //Verifica o estado e faz a alteração na fonte da célula

if ([[arrayProcessosLocal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]  valueForKey:@"lido"] == 1) {

        //Torna fonte bold
       cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];

      [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [processosLocal valueForKey:@"processo"],[processosLocal valueForKey:@"data_pdf"]]];

        return cell;
    }else{

        // Exibe a fonte normal caso o valor de "lido" seja 0 (zero)        
         [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [processosLocal valueForKey:@"processo"], [processosLocal valueForKey:@"data_pdf"]]];
        return cell;
    }
```

[image: Antes de selecionar a célula]

[image: Após selecionar a célula, ver a conversa e voltar à UITableView]

Como fazer esse processo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De uma forma um pouco mais simples, considerando que você tenha alguma forma de persistir esses dados, você pode fazer algo assim no método `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` da sua tabela:

```
if ([objPessoa isSaved]) {
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
} else {
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
}
```

Considerando que **objPessoa** é o seu objeto da base de dados e **isSaved** indica se o objeto foi salvo ou não (se foi visitado ou não).

E no método `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` você tem o esquema que realiza a visita e então pode atualizar a linha para retirar o negrito:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
}
```

Veja se isso te atende.

Comment: Eu ja tenho uma persistencia no core data, e eu fiz uma logica parecida com a sua, porem não funcionou... vou tentar com seu codigo e ja digo se funcionou ou nao! Obrigado!

Comment: coloquei o trecho do código que fiz, da uma olhada e ve oque acha... ainda não fiz o teste com o codigo que vc me passou, mas vou fazer jaja!

Comment: parece que quando ele detecta o if, ele entra naquele padrão e determina o valor da fonte para todas as células seguintes :/. O mesmo resultado que tive com o seu código eu tive com o meu... vc viu o meu código? Quando coloco  uma exclamação (inverto a avalização lógica do if) if(![meuObjeto isSaved]) ele coloca tudo em negrito,  mesmo lendo do banco que algumas já estão LIDO ele as coloca novamente em negrito.

Comment: Encontrei o problema, eu estava fazendo uma comparação errada entre os tipos e o Xcode não pode verificar este erro pois só é possível saber o TIPO em run time! 

 Vou postar a resposta!

Answer (score 0):

O problema é o TIPO do dado de LIDO no `Core Data`. Pois o tipo no `Core Data` para o campo LIDO é `STRING` e eu estava fazendo uma comparação direta com um `INT` no `IF()`;

Código errado em `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if ([[arrayProcessosLocal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]  valueForKey:@"lido"] == 1) {
.
.
.
// Demais implementação
```

Código Correto!

```
if ([[[arrayProcessosLocal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]  valueForKey:@"lido"] isEqual:@"1"]) {
.
.
.
// Demais implementação
```

Não tem como o Xcode saber o tipo do dado que vem do `Core Data`, e no tempo de execução não houve problemas pois o tipo `STRING` para o `if()`, equivale a valor numérico, então para fazer a verificação correta tive que utilizar o método `isEqual:`